# Google Web Starter Kit implementation in Fat-Free framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework, starter-kits

Did you test the new Google Web Starter Kit?
https://developers.google.com/web/starter-kit/

I'm asked to use it, but I can't find a suitable way to implement it in a MVC I've created with the Fat Free Framework (it's PHP).

The logic would be to add it in the Views, but then how do I profit of the automation tasks, livereload, etc.?

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions ;)

Comment: Depends on the situation. The question ins subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I initialized the Starter Kit at my root folder and then customized Gulpfile.js to suit my own architecture.

I also configured the integrated web server to use a proxy set by my local Wamp server settings.